# Как отрыть фрагмент но при открытии положить в стак перед ним еще один фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть `активити 1` в котором загружени фрагмент и в этом фрагменте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую я хочу, чтоб открывалась `activity 2` в которой есть `main fragment`, `detail fragment`.

Так вот мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку открыть `activity 2` и загрузить в нее `detail fragment` , но в стак перед ним положить `main fragment`, чтоб при нажатии кнопки назад `detail fragment` уничтожался и юзер видел `main fragment`

Если не получилось обьяснить спрашивайте.

Как это правильно сделать?

Просто мне не кажется, что правильно при открытии `activity 2` загружать `main fragment` и сразу же сверху загружать `detail fragment`... Мне кажется есть способ просто указать, что нужно положить в стак

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что можно добавить фрагмент в бэкстек не загружая его и не аттача к активити. Как вариант, переопределить кнопку назад и вручную обработать данную навигацию.

Comment: Думаю стоит копать в направлении метода onBackPressed() и там с фрагмент менеджером повоевать. В стиле если последний фрагмент - detail то тогда вместо возврата сделать новую транзакцию которая вставит main. ну и изначально при открытии активити2 detail в бекстек не добавлять. тогда кнопка назад стоя на main вернется к активити1. Пока нет возможности закодить и проверить, но самому интересно. Если найду решение оформлю ответом)